# Directing the user to the device settings if access to the location is denied

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an application, it is necessary to access the location to use the application

But I don't know how to direct it to the settings about denying access to the Location

I put check when I run the application that the application could not access the site, it directs it to this view

```
struct LocationRequestView: View {

var body: some View {
   
    ZStack {
        
        Button(action: { LocationManager.shared.requestAllowLocation()}) {
            Text("Allow access to the Location")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I want when the status is **case .denied:** in **didChangeAuthorization**, it directs it to the settings to activate the Location

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@Published var userLocation: CLLocation?
let manager = CLLocationManager()
static let shared = LocationManager()

@Published var cityName = ""
@Published var countryName = ""

override init() {
    super.init()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    
    switch status {
    case .notDetermined:
        requestAllowLocation()
        print("Not1")
    case .restricted:
        print("Not2")
    case .denied:
        print("Not3")
///Here
    case .authorizedAlways:
        print("Not4")
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        print("Not5")
    case .authorized:
        break
    }
}
func requestAllowLocation() {
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    guard let lastLocation = locations.last else { return}
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        
        self.userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(self.userLocation!) { (placemarks, error) in
            self.processResponse(withPlacemarks: placemarks, error: error)
            
        }
    }
    
}

func processResponse(withPlacemarks placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Unable to Reverse Geocode Location (\(error))")

        } else {
            if let placemarks = placemarks, let placemark = placemarks.first {
                
                self.cityName = placemark.locality ?? ""
                self.countryName = placemark.country ?? ""
                
            } else {
                print("No matching address found")
            }
        }
    }

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

func fetchCountryAndCity(for location: CLLocation?) {
    guard let location = location else { return }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Look into the new temporary permisssion. You can get one time persuasion very easily after the user denies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```swift
if let url = URL.init(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```